# DropCreateAlways database initializer does not work when put in Web.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following in my Web.config

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <contexts>
    <context type="Models.EVRMDBContext, EVRM">
      <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.DropCreateAlways`1[[Models.EVRMDBContext, EVRM]], EntityFramework" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

However as soon as I use/query my DBContext the database is not created. When I set the databaseInitializer in Global.asax using

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EVRM.Models.EVRMDBContext>());
```

It does initialize the database.

(Using Entity Framework 5 with MVC4)

Comment: Can you try to set it programmatically (just to determine whether the problem is in the configuration or not)?  You can do so by calling System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Models.EVRMDBContext>());  for example in the default static constructor for the Models.EVRMDBContext class.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of this? Was it just the typo, or something else?

Comment: @Ryan Look at Bjorn's answer below.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the web.config, should be "System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways" instead of "System.Data.Entity.DropCreateAlways"